# Can someone see why I can't accept an answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, accepted-answer

Why can't I accept an answer on this

[Removing items from data bound array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686813/removing-items-from-data-bound-array) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set a bounty on it in the past?

There are a number of questions about this on meta - [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413/why-an-answer-cant-be-accepted-after-an-unresolved-bounty) - for example. Jeff answers to the effect that if...

> the bounty expires with no auto-accept, and no answer can ever be accepted for that question.

Comment: I might have - its been a whie.