# Why can't I accept an answer or delete this topic?

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can someone see why I can't accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/can-someone-see-why-i-cant-accept-an-answer)

[Showing content over a flash 9 swf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209085/showing-content-over-a-flash-9-swf)

I'm trying to get my accepted questions percentage to 100%, and this topic is killing me. What can I do? I can't accept any answers (no checkbox), and I can't delete the post because it has too many responses.

Comment: Don't worry, I don't think anyone is looking down on you for a 99% accept rate. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a bounty and it expired before you accepted an answer, you can't then accept any answer in the future.

See also: [Can someone see why I can't accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25745/can-someone-see-why-i-cant-accept-an-answer)

Comment: I honestly didn't remember that I'd answer the linked question!

Comment: Then I should still be able to delete my post to get my percentage of accepted questions up, or that calculation should ignore questions I can no longer close/accept. The only alternative, I see, is to get four other accounts up to voting power and close the topic with a vote.